# Autocomplete in Anaconda

Tags: autocomplete, anaconda

I would kindly ask for in-kind assistance please.
I am using Anaconda 3 (the latest version) on Windows. 
It appears that autocomplete works with libraries only e.g.  when I type pd (pd is imported pandas library) and put dot I get pip up list of functions.
When I try to do the same for dataframe object (which has been defined earlier as below:

```
 df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

I get no pop up list.
Any ideas what might be the problem and how to resolve it?
In addition, why help (ctrl+ i) does not work with dataframe objects e.g. when placing cursor in front of `df.dropna()` I see no help in upper right help window.
Please advise. Thanks

Comment: how are you using anaconda?  through a terminal?  through Spyder? through Jupyter?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I am Windows 7 user. I am starting spyder through command prompt and dbl-clicking on icon.  Jupyter  cannot be started in any way. Moreover, I cannot launch no application through Anaconda Navigator.